# what is the meaning of this phrase?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am not looking for a fact here, I know that this is highly debatable. My question is about the information mentioned here in the sentence:

- Many scientists believe that global warming and its consequences are highly influenced by human activities and not by natural fluctuations.

I understand it as a comparison i.e. global warming is more affected by human behavior than by nature. Am I right? Or does it mean it is not affected by nature at all?

I believe the word *highly* here is key, but I am not very sure.

p.s. not a native speaker, obviously :)

Comment: Including ***highly*** (or, for example, ***significantly***) doesn't necessarily force the meaning *global warming is caused **more** by human activity than by natural fluctuations*. If you specifically want to say that one is more relevant than the other you need to express this more explicitly. And I'm not sure what it means to say either human activity *or* natural fluctuations "influence" the *consequences* of global warming. And I know you didn't ask for "facts", but I think we're way past the point where natural fluctuations are a significant factor in terms of what we have to do.

Comment: This is actually a sentence in a text I asked my students to translate. Some of them translated the sentence as *global warming is more affected by humans than by nature* and some translated it as *global warming is affected by humans not by nature*. So, you're saying it could mean either?

Comment: As a translator  myself, I can tell you that highly just means very or very much influenced. The structure is: Many A believe that B and C are very influenced by D and not very influenced by E. Also, there is no comparative, really. There is B and C are very influenced by D and B and C are not very influenced by E. They would be equal in strength.

Comment: @user121256: The meaning of your *exact* cited text unambiguously asserts that human activities affect (cause?) global warming more than natural fluctuations do. But that's because of ***and not by***, not ***highly***. The only potential ambiguity is whether that contrastive element is a cut-down version of ***and not highly influenced by*** or just ***and not influenced by*** (which latter could be taken to imply that natural fluctuations are completely irrelevant, rather than just being a "lesser factor").

Comment: What precisely was meant cannot be accurately determined.  The phrasing is highly ambiguous, and, given that, not really worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1):

The word *highly* is important here. The sentence is discussing what *highly* influences global warming.

- Do many scientists believe human activities highly influence global warming? Yes.
- Do those many scientists believe natural fluctuations highly influence global warming? No.

The word 'highly' leaves open the possibility that those scientists believe natural fluctuations *do* influence global warming, but only slightly.

Comment: *This product quickly killed all the weeds in my garden, but not my prized chrysanthemums‎*. I think it would be stretching a point to say that including the word ***quickly*** there somehow leaves open the possibility that the product did actually kill my chrysanthemums (but *slowly*, not quickly). Or indeed that it quickly killed only *some* of my chrysanthemums (the rest either surviving unscathed, or dying somewhat later).

Comment: I admit there is ambiguity - I would say your sentence *might* mean that the chrysanthemums were killed slowly, but probably doesn't. Likewise the OP sentence *might* mean that natural fluctuations don't influence global warming at all, but probably doesn't. I would say that the use of 'and' makes it less likely, compared with 'but'.